# Can anybody explain orthogonal basis for constant polynomials?

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I have a problem.

$(f,g)= \int_{1}^{3} f(x)g(x) \, dx$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}$

I have to find out a nearest constant polynomials to $f$.

So, I assumed $a$ to be a orthonormal basis for constant function, and by using inner

product of $(a,a)$, which is $2a^2=1$ and I got $\pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$  for my 
orthonormal basis. But if it has a orthonormal basis, does that imply that it has also 
orthogonal basis too? but there is only one basis for constant function and I can not 
find any two basis that inner product of two would be zero.

Did I misunderstand something?

two basis which

Comment: I would suggest revising the language of the problem and clarify it a bit more.

Comment: Do you mean, you are trying to find the constant polynomial closest to $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with respect to the given ($L^2$) inner product?

Comment: that is exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

Since we're approximating $f$ by a constant function, and the space of constant functions is spanned by a single basis element, there's no reason to appeal (explicitly) to bases here.

Per the comments, we want to find the constant function $g(x) = c$ that minimizes the distance from $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with respect to the given inner product, or in other words, find the constant $c$ that minimizes
$$(f - g, f - g) = \int_1^3 (f - g)^2 dx = \int_1^3 \left(\frac{1}{x} - c\right)^2 dx.$$

We can expand the integrand, integrate, then differentiate w.r.t. $c$, and solve to find its the optimal value of $c$, but it's slightly faster to differentiate w.r.t. $c$ first and then integrate (this comes at the cost of remembering and checking the condition that allows us to differentiate under the integral sign):
$$\frac{d}{dc}(f - g, f - g) = \frac{d}{dc}\int_1^3 \left(\frac{1}{x} - c\right)^2 dx
=\int_1^3 \frac{d}{dc}\left[\left(\frac{1}{x} - c \right)\right]^2 dx \\= \int_1^3 2\left(c - \frac{1}{x}\right) dx = \left. 2(cx - \log x)\right\vert_1^3 = 4c - 2 \log 3.$$ The quantity $(f - g, f - g)$ has a (uniquely) critical value where this expression is zero, namely at $c = \frac{1}{2} \log 3 = \log \sqrt{3}$.

(Strictly speaking needs to argue why this is a minimum rather than another sort of critical point. One way to do do this is to show that $$\left.\frac{d^2}{dc^2}\right\vert_{c = \frac{1}{2} \log 3} (f - g, f - g) > 0.)$$

**Edit** Alternatively, we can just project onto the subspace. If we abuse notation to let $c$ represent the function with constant value $c$, the projection of $f$ onto the subspace spanned by $c$ is
$$\frac{(f, c)}{(c, c)} c = \frac{\int_1^3 cf \,dx}{\int_1^c c^2 \,dx} c = \frac{c^2 \int_1^3 \frac{dx}{x}}{c^2 \int_1^3 dx} = \frac{\log 3}{2}$$
as desired. Note that if $c$ has using length, i.e., if $(c, c) = 1$, then the projection map simplifies to
$$f \mapsto (f, c) c.$$

In general, given an orthonormal basis $(w_1, \ldots w_m)$ of a vector subspace $W$ of an inner product space $(V, (\, \cdot\, , \,\cdot\,))$, the orthogonal projection onto $W$ has the simple formula
$$v \mapsto (v, w_1) w_1 + \cdots + (v, w_m) w_m,$$
and this map is independent of which basis $(w_a)$ of $W$ is used.

Comment: this was a great work, but can you approximate this by projection of f onto subspace?

Comment: If you wanted a solution using a specific method you should have specified that in your question, but I'll write up another proof using projections explicitly.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you find the answer useful.

Comment: That was very helpful, and one more question. Is there a orthogonal set for constant function? constant function has only one basis, and I don't think there are two basis that would be zero

Comment: The space of constant functions on an interval is $1$-dimensional (any constant function is a constant multiple of the function $g(x) = c$), and so any basis of the space of constant functions has exactly one element. By constrast, the space of linear (actually, affine) functions $y = mx + b$ on an interval is two-dimensional, and has basis $(f_0, f_1)$, where $f_0(x) = 1$ and $f_1(x) = 1$.

Comment: So, there is no orthogonal basis for constant function? If then, there should be no orthonormal basis too? seems like you could have orthonormal basis if you make norm equal to 1.  Sorry for asking so many questions, but I am really struggling with this concept

Comment: and f0(x) should be x? example that you've given me above

Comment: Any basis can be turned into an orthogonal basis using the Gram-Schmidt algorithm. In particular, given the basis $\{1\}$ of the subspace of constant functions, we can produce an orthogonal basis exactly as you did in your question: Scaling $1$ by a suitable constant gives you the unit-length vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and since any basis of this subspace has exactly one vector, $\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$ is an orthogonal basis.

Comment: last question, definition of orthogonal basis is that inner product of every pair of element is 0. If 1/square root of 2 is a orthogonal basis, then how does that imply that inner product would be zero?

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment should read "orthonormal" basis, not "orthogonal" (which is still true, but not the point in this case).

Comment: Anyway, the condition $(v, w) = 0$ only applies to pairs of *distinct* vectors $v, w$. If the basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ is orthonormal, then each $v$ has length $1$, that is $(v, v) = 1$.

Comment: and what would be the orthogonal basis for constant function? I think that if there is a orthonormal basis, then there is also orthgonal basis too. if 1/square root 2 is orthonomal basis, what would be the orthogonal basis?  really last

Comment: Orthogonal just means that for any distinct vectors $v, w$ in the basis we have $(v, w) = 0$, but there is no condition on the lengths of the basis vectors. For an orthonormal we also require that the vectors $v$ in the basis have unit (or "normalized") length, that is, that $(v, v) = 1$. For a $1$-dimensional vector space $V$, any basis has only one element, so there are no two vectors to check, and so *any* basis of $V$ is orthogonal.